# Reiniciar ciclo while JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while, bucles

He estado probando algunas cosas en `JavaScript` y, dado que estoy aprendiendo, en la práctica me he encontrado con un error ejecutando un ciclo `while()`que describo seguidamente.

Lo que necesito es realizar un `prompt()` que pida una contraseña al usuario ingresarla, tal como "Miguel", y que me devuelva un mensaje de "bienvenida" (Parte resuelta). Ahora, también necesito tener un número limitado de intentos y que al sobrepasar éste me de un mensaje de "error".

Todo lo he resuelto con un ciclo `while()`que contiene las condiciones que dejare en el ejemplo del código, pero el problema se encuentra en que al ejecutar la condición donde cuenta el numero de intentos (`intento++`) hasta cumplir el máximo de intentos permitidos y el código cierra la ejecución (`break;`), por ende no me reinicia o continua con el ciclo, esto quiere decir que no vuelve a ejecutar el `prompt()` y además alcanza el número máximo de intentos sin ejecutar todo el ciclo nuevamente.

La idea es que se ejecute de tal manera que si introduzco una contraseña "incorrecta" se sume el valor de `intento` una vez cada vez que el ciclo reinicia (volviendo a ejecutar desde la aparición del prompt hasta el final), de manera que si introducimos mal nuevamente la contraseña este intento se sume nuevamente a `intento`, cosa que no pasa ya que se ejecuta `intento++` hasta que llega a tres y el programa se tiene que cerrar por llegar al máximo de intentos, sin que el usuario haya introducido nada.

```js
var pass = prompt("Introduzca la contraseña");
var intento = 0;

while (pass != undefined) {

  if (intento < 3) {

    if (pass == "Miguel") {

      alert("Bienvenido Miguel.");
      break;

    } else if (pass != "Miguel") {

      intento++;
      alert("Introduzca una clave valida.");
      continue;

    }

  } else {

    alert("Ha intentado demasiadas veces.");
    break;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema básicamente está aquí: <s>`alert("Introduzca una clave valida.");`</s>.  Si en lugar del `alert` usas algo como `pass = prompt("Introduzca una clave valida.");` funcionaría, porque estarías mostrando el mensaje y recogiendo el posible `prompt` en la variable `pass`.

No obstante, te propongo esta lógica en la que se van descontando los intentos y se informa al usuario de que le quedan `n` intentos. Es así como suelen funcionar este tipo de cosas.

Nótese que `pendingIntents` es establecido a `2` porque el usuario habrá agotado la primera posibilidad en el 1er prompt, y por tanto sólo le quedarán dos.

```js
var pendingIntents=2;
var pass = prompt(`Introduzca la contraseña. Dispone de ${pendingIntents+1} intentos`);
while (pass != undefined) {

  if (pendingIntents > 0) {

    if (pass == "Miguel") {

      alert("Bienvenido Miguel.");
      break;

    } else if (pass != "Miguel") {

      pass = prompt(`Introduzca una clave valida. Quedan ${pendingIntents} intentos`);
      pendingIntents--;
      continue;

    }

  } else {

    alert("Ha intentado demasiadas veces.");
    break;

  }

}
```

Comment: Esto me hizo entenderlo a la perfección!! Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Hay unas cuantas cosas que me llaman la atencion en tu codigo:

- Todo el bucle se inicia solo si la contraseña introducida no es indefinida, pero no ocurre nada de nada si lo es, es decir, muestras que una contraseña es incorrecta,  pero un indefinida no seria necesario remarcar también que lo es?
- El `continue` se tiene a utilizar para saltar una de las iteraciones de un loop, pero en tu caso el hecho de que este es igual a que no este, no hace ningún cambio ya que si dejas que el loop termine de forma natural tampoco ejecutara ninguna liena de codigo ni entrara en ningun `if`:

---

**Explicacion:**
El problema de que se termine de golpe viene a que no hay nada que cambie la pass en el momento en el que haces `continue`. Solo haces un alert pero no hay ningun otro momento en el que se pueda establecer una nueva contraseña, por lo tanto el loop se vuelve a ejecutar exatacmente con la misma contraseña errone antes hasta que salta el numero de intentos.

**Solucion:**
De esta forma puedes gestionar de una mejor manera los errores que te pueda generara el codigo:

```js
pass = prompt("Introduzca la contraseña");
var intentosFallidos = 1;
// Si entra en el else significa que ya ha realizado un intontoFallido.
var correcto = false;

// Repetir el bucle mientras los intentos fallidos sean menores a 3
// Y mientras que no haya acertado la contraseña
 
while(intentosFallidos<3 && !correcto){
  // Si la contraseña coincide: El login es correcto
  if(pass == "Miguel"){
    correcto = true;
  // sino el numero de intentos fallidos se aumenta y se vuleve a preguntar por otra
  } else {
    intentosFallidos++;
    pass = prompt("Introduzca una clave valida");
  }
}
// A este punto solo se llega si bien se ha realizado correctamente el login
// o bien se ha superado el numero de intentos, por lo tanto:
if(correcto){
  alert("Bienvenido Miguel")
}else {
  alert("Ha superado el maxion de intentos");
}
```

Comment: Una explicación extraordinaria, gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1):

No te líes de verdad, prueba éste código fácil y que funciona:

```
'use strict'

var contra;
var contador=0;

while(contador<=2 && contra!='Miguel'){
    contra = prompt('Introduce contra');

    if(contra==''){
        console.log('No has puesto nada');
    }

    contador++;
    alert(contador);
}

if(contra=='Miguel'){
    console.log('Bienvenido Miguel');

}else{
    console.log('Se acabaron los intentos');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta forma:

```
do{
    var pass = prompt("Introduzca la contraseña");
    var intento = 0;
    var intentoAcertado = false;

    while (pass != undefined) {

      if (intento < 3) {

        if (pass == "Miguel") {

           alert("Bienvenido Miguel.");
           intentoAcertado=true; 
           break;

        } else if (pass != "Miguel") {

           intento++;
           alert("Introduzca una clave valida.");
           continue;

        }

     } else {

        alert("Ha intentado demasiadas veces.");
        break;

     }

    }
}while(!intentoAcertado)
```

Comment: Hola!! esto lo que crea es un bucle que hasta que la condición `intentoAcertado` no sea `true` no va a dejar de ejecutarse por lo que el segundo bucle tendrá aun el problema, hasta que la respuesta sea correcta, por lo que no solo no elimina la duda si no que ya no existe un numero máximo de intentos, pero gracias... aun así.

Comment: Entonces no entendí bien lo que quieres tratar de hacer, podrías explicarte un poco mejor?

Comment: Editare la pregunta para que sea un poco mas "entendible". Gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, no hay ningún contador progresivo ni tampoco una variable que disminuya su cantidad a medida que el usuario introduzca un dato que no se corresponda a la respuesta correcta.

Una posibilidad es hacer un while con un contador en su interior o hacer un bucle for.