# alertas para php que no se pierdan cuando se recargan la página

Tags: php, html, botón, alert, refresh

Existe algun alert que aunque se recargue la pagina no se pierda el alert hasta darle en su botón de aceptar y así poder redireccionar a otra pagina

Comment: Lo que buscas es [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), Tienes un ejemplo [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187065/29967). Puedes recoger lo que se escriba y redirigir o hacer otra cosa.

Comment: Otra posibilidad sería usar [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), si sólo quieres emitir una confirmación y recuperar el botón pulsado para lanzar una acción.

Comment: Podrías usar una cookie, si no existe, muestras la alerta cada que se recargue la página y dejas de mostrarla si existe.